# Variable is treated as a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying out the node-mysql module on node js. What I want to do is to be able to come up with an object like this:

```
{'room1':'Room 1','room2':'Room 2','room3':'Room 3'}
```

Here's the code:

```
var boom  = results;
   var rooms = [];
   var index = 0;
   var name = 'session';
    for(var b in boom){
        var ses = name + index;
        rooms[b] = {ses : boom[b]['ses_title']};
        index++;
    }
```

The ses variable is being treated as a string in the code above. And I end up with something like this:

```
[{ses : 'class session'} , {ses : 'team session'}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign key names like that. Use [bracket notation](http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/js-dot-notation/) and it should work:

```
var boom  = results;
var rooms = [];
var index = 0;
var name = 'session';
for(var b in boom){
 rooms[b] = {};
 rooms[b][name + index] = boom[b]['ses_title']};
 index += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use something like:

```
rooms[b] = {};
rooms[b][ses] = boom[b]['ses_title'];
```

This is because keys in object literals are always interpreted literally, not evaluated.