# RethinkDB using .Update and Variables

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb

I want to manipulate a field for a given ID, and the field depends on user Input. So I have...

```
var fieldName = (got from the user)

r.db('DataBase').table('table').get(ID).update({fieldName: 'YES'})
```

This doesn't work because RethinkDB doesn't recognize 'fieldName' as a variable, and instead makes a new field called fieldName, instead of the value stored 'fieldName'.

Is there a way around this or no?

Thank you!

Comment: ALRIGHT. I think I got it! Found help [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9799181/variable-is-treated-as-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Found the way to do it!

Add [] around your variable. This apparently works so far

```
r.db('DataBase').table('table').get(ID).update({[fieldName]: 'YES'})
```